# allOddBits return 1

Tags: c, bit

Hello the function is called allOddBits with one input so if the function identifies 1 when the odd numbered bits are then it will return 1 otherwise it return 0;
Thank you for the help in advance. 
We are only allowed to use these ! ~ & ^ | + << >> bit operation not more than 12 times. This way is always returning a 1 which is not correct because when the value of 'a' doesn't have odd numbered bits equal to 1, it should not return 1.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
unsigned a,c;
a= 0xAAAAAAAA; // given  bits, it can be anything
c= a>>31;      // Shifting 31 bits to the right and fill in 0 instead 
c= ~c;         // flipping the bits so it can all be 1 except for LSB

printf(": %u\n", !!c);
}
```

Never mind guys,.. I figured out the solution but it did take some time. I appreciate your input though.

Comment: And besides the function header, what have you tried?

Comment: We aren't here to solve your homework for you.  Try to figure it out and then ask questions for things you can't solve.

Comment: It's not funny until you enter the question title as-is in Google.

Comment: Meta : in such cases, should we post "partial answers" that guide the OP without actually giving the answer ?

Comment: I could do it so it can return 1 but the problem is it only just returning 1 for everything.

Comment: Could you add comments to the lines involving `c` so we know what you're trying to do ?

Comment: where is `allOddBits`

Comment: I will just first do it on the main function and if it works then I will implement it on the actual function. @MattMcNabb

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned int x = strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 10);
unsigned int a = 0x55555555;  // or 0xAAAAAAAA if you count LSB as bit 0
return ((x & a) == a);
```

Comment: No `==`, has he said ;)